# Is it possible to export * as foo in typescript

Tags: typescript, module, export

I can:

```
import * as foo from './foo'
```

But can't seem to export the same:

```
export * as foo from './foo'
```

This doesn't seem to work either...:

```
import * as fooImport from './foo';
export const foo = fooImport;
```

Any ideas?

--- UPDATE ---

> What are you trying to achieve?

Basically, I am working on implementing an `ngrx/store` backend for my app.  I want to organize my code like this:

```
app/core/
  index.ts
  viewer/
    index.ts
    viewer-actions.ts
    viewer-reducer.ts
  view-data/
    index.ts
    view-data-actions.ts
    view-data-reducer.ts
```

And I want to use my `index.ts` files to chain up all the exports from each subset (common paradigm).

However, I want to keep things *namespaced*.  Each of my `xxx-reducer.ts` and `xxx-actions.ts` files have exports of the same name (`reducer`, `ActionTypes`, `Actions`, ...) so normal chaining would result in a name collision.  What I am trying to do is allow for all of the exports from `xxx-actions` and `xxx-reducer` to be *re-exported* as `xxx`.  This would allow me to:

```
import { viewer, viewerData } from './core';

...
    private viewer: Observable<viewer.Viewer>;
    private viewData: Observable<viewData.ViewData>;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.viewer = this.store.let(viewer.getViewer());
        this.viewData = this.store.let(viewData.getViewData());
    }
```

Instead of the more verbose:

```
import * as viewer from './core/viewer';
import * as viewerData from './core/viewer-data';

...
```

Thats the gist anyway...

Answer (score 61, accepted):

## TypeScript 3.8 or Later

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59712387/1108891 for details.

## Before TypeScript 3.7 or Earlier

> Is it possible to export * as foo in typescript

Nope. You can, however, use a two step process:

src/core/index.ts

```
import * as Foo from "./foo";
import * as Bar from "./bar";

export {
    Foo,
    Bar,
}
```

src/index.ts

```
import { Foo, Bar } from "./core";

function FooBarBazBop() {
    Foo.Baz;
    Foo.Bop;
    Bar.Baz;
    Bar.Bop;
}
```

src/core/foo/index.ts **and** src/core/bar/index.ts

```
export * from "./baz";
export * from "./bop";
```

src/core/foo/baz.ts **and** src/core/bar/baz.ts

```
export class Baz {

}
```

src/core/foo/bop.ts **and** src/core/bar/bop.ts

```
export class Bop {

}
```

See also: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: Yeah, i read that, and was trying to combine **Import the entire module into a single variable, and use it to access the module exports** with **Re-exports**

Comment: Awesome...  your update is exactly what i was looking for (even though it is 2 steps).  Thank you.

Comment: This seems like a missing feature. Why won't it work? Are they trying to maintain compatibility with ESNext?

Comment: @rakim Yes. They are trying to maintain compatibility with ESNext. That is a fundamental goal of TypeScript.

Comment: There is a draft up for it in ECMAScript 2021.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: It seems this is no longer accurate; see Przemek's answer.

Answer (score 52):

Since **TypeScript 3.8** has been released you are able to **add alias for your exports**.

Example:

```
export * as utilities from "./utilities.js";
```

Ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html

Comment: ts 3.8 is already released: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript/v/3.8.2

Comment: I am still not able to use this.
My system is installed with typescript 3.8.3.

Comment: Me neither. : (

Comment: TS38 does support it, but webpack does not: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10460. If you set module to "es2015" in tsconfig.json then it will be downleveled to something webpack currently supports

Comment: is it possible to export selected functions from current file under some name like `utilities`  without using `namespaces`?