# Preserve directory structure of a package for importing

Tags: node.js, typescript, import

I'm trying to create a package with directory structure as follow:

```
src/
    folder1/
        index.ts
        ...
    folder2/
        index.ts
        ...
    folder3/
        index.ts
        ...
.
.
.
```

And I would like to import it as `import { Class1 } from '@package/folder1'`, `import { Class2 } from '@package/folder2'`, etc.

At this moment, I'm able to import my classes like `import { Class1 } from '@package/lib/folder1'`. Is it possible to achieve my expected behavior?

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "rootDirs": ["./src/folder1"],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "pretty": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "lib"]
}
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias?

Comment: Not exactly. It is useful indeed but my problem is just the `lib` directory. I want the root of my package to be `lib`. So I don't need to specify it in the import.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this feature is not out-of-the-box in the version of Typescript I'm using (3.7.4). The package `module-alias` could be a workaround but it looks like Typescript 3.8 will allow adding aliases to the exports.

- [Typescript 3.8 announcement link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-8-beta/)
- [Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728140/is-it-possible-to-export-as-foo-in-typescript)

Answer (score -1):

Setting the output directory as the package directory in the following manner should solve your problem:

```
"outDir": "."
```

This will help you make imports without the `"./lib"` that currently your `"outDir"` refers to in the tsconfig.json.