# Export other module as namespace

Tags: typescript

I have several modules exporting various types, classes etc.
Is it possible to create another module that aggregates all the exports from those modules in a nice way? Specifically, is it possible to from one module export all exports of another module as a sub-module or namespace?

sub.ts:

```
export const foo = 42;
export const bar = 43;
```

index.ts:

```
import * as Sub from './sub.ts'
// Now Sub.foo and Sub.bar exists

export class Foo {
}

// export all members from sub as 'Sub'
export Sub;
```

my-client.ts:

```
import {Sub, Foo} from './index'

const x = Sub.foo;
const y = new Foo();
```

The `export Sub` line gives `expression statement is not assignment or call`.

How can something like this be done to form a logical entrypoint to a module consisting of several other modules' functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
// export all members from sub as 'Sub'
export {  
  Sub
};
```

for more info checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/42731800/908464

Comment: This is awesome, strange I didn't find that while searching. Thanks a lot.